# Making yiistrap modal window draggable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii-extensions

How can I make yiistrap modal window draggable using jquery ui? I know how to do it for bootstrap but how should I make changes for yiistrap? In bootstrap it is like this

```
$("#myModal").draggable({
handle: ".modal-header"
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer to my problem and thus I am posting my code for making modal window draggable in yiistrap. I hope it will be helpful to others also.

```
<?php $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbModal', array(
    'id'=>'myModal',
    'fade' => false,
    'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width: 1253px; margin-left: -646px; margin-top: -95px; left: 610px; height: 648px'),
    'options' => array('backdrop' => 'static', 'keyboard' => true)
    )); 
?>
<script>
$(function(){$("#myModal").draggable().resizable();});
</script>
//Modal Header Part
//Modal Body Part
//Modal Footer Part
```

Don't forget to include jquery-ui.css.